# Replacing Multiples of numbers in Fibonacci series using Flag method

Tags: java, fibonacci

As the title suggests, I have code for a Fibonacci series and my goal is to replace multiples of numbers (3, 5, 7 and combinations of them) in the series with  a word. I was suggested to use a flag in my if loop to check for the printed phrase, and if the phrase is printed, to skip that number. Essentially, what I want the output to look like is:

1 1 2 skip 8 13 skip 34 55

(this is replacing multiple of three only, for now).

Instead, what I am getting is:

1 1 2 3 skip5 8 13 21 skip34 55

Here is my code as of now:

```
int febCount = 50;
long[] feb = new long[febCount];
feb[0] = 1;
feb[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < febCount; i++) {
 feb[i] = feb[i - 1] + feb[i - 2];
}

for (int i = 0; i < febCount; i++) {
 System.out.print(feb[i] + ((i % 10 == 9) ? "\n" : " "));
 if (feb[i] % 3 == 0)
  System.out.print("skip");
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: There are no syntax errors that I see :/

Comment: Your code would never compile if there were syntax errors. Debugging will lead you to find the problem. I'll give you a hint: are things being executed in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the code you have provided and attempt to understand why it's not working.

```
//The first thing we do is setup the loop to iterate through the fib numbers.
//This looks good.
for (int i = 0; i < febCount; i++) {
 //Here we print out the fibonacci number we are on, unconditionally.
 //This means that every fibonacci number will be printed no matter what number it is
 //we don't want that.
 System.out.print(feb[i] + ((i % 10 == 9) ? "\n" : " "));
 //After we print the number, we check to see if it is a multiple of three.
 //maybe we should be waiting to print until then?
 if (feb[i] % 3 == 0)
  System.out.print("skip");
}
```

Now that we have walked  through the code, we can propose a new solution.
Let's try updating the loop so that it wait's to print the fibonacci number until AFTER we've checked to see if it meets our conditions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < febCount; i++) {
    if (feb[i] % 3 == 0 || feb[i] % 5 == 0 || feb[i] % 7 == 0) { //check if multiple of 3 5 or 7
         System.out.println(" Skip ");
    } else { //if it's not a multiple, then print the number
       System.out.println(" " + feb[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank so so much. I was wondering all day about this and it was a matter of switching around the order that it's printed in.

Comment: What would be the case if I wanted to replace multiples of 5 with a different phrase and multiples of 7 with another phrase?

Comment: Right now the way the code is written we are treating each case of 3 5 and 7 as the same thing, your first step should be to make each of those their own case

Comment: So right now, I have separated them. I'm getting close to the results I want, but for the cases of 5 and 7, I still have the problem of printing only the word instead of both the word and number. Would simply placing another. Would placing another  }else{ System.out.print(feb[i]); after each case work?